# Apple TV application does not resign active on sleep mode

Tags: objective-c, tvos, apple-tv

I have a TVOS app where I am trying to update the UI after the Apple TV comes back from sleep mode.

I would expect that on entering sleep mode the app would call either/or/both of "applicationWillResignActive" and "applicationDidEnterBackground". This would allow me to set up an NSNotificaiton to listen out for "applicationDidBecomeActive" and/or "applicationWillEnterForeground" and update the data in the app accordingly.

If I force a sleep with the app open by holding the home button for a few seconds the process seems correct.

1. applicationWillResignActive - pop up appears.
2. applicationDidBecomeActive is then called.
3. Press the sleep button.
4. applicationWillResignActive called.
5. applicationDidEnterBackground called.
6. My app is now in the background and the Apple TV is in sleep mode (black screen).
7. Press "Menu" button on the remote to wake the Apple TV.
8. applicationWillEnterForeground is then called.
9. applicationDidBecomeActive is the called.
10. I can now update the UI.

However this order is not followed if you just let the app enter sleep mode naturally. My Apple TV settings are as follows:

Screensaver is set to become active on the Apple TV after 2 mins.

Sleep mode is set to become active after 15 mins.

1. After 2 mins applicationWillResignActive is called.
2. Screensaver is now active.
3. After another 15 mins has passed the app starts to change from screensaver mode to sleep mode.
4. At this point applicationDidEnterBackground is called.
5. The app becomes active again for a brief moment as applicationWillEnterForeground quickly called followed by applicationDidBecomeActive.
6. applicationWillResignActive is then called - and at which point I'd expect applicationDidEnterBackground would trigger and the device would go into sleep mode (black screen).
7. However this is not the case. The screen does go black but applicationDidBecomeActive is triggered again.

So effectively, the app is still active, but the device is in sleep mode. Is this (correct) default behaviour? On waking I cannot refresh my UI as nothing gets called when the device wakes. None of the app state methods, nor any of the view life cycle methods.

So in short, I need to know:

1. Is this default behaviour?
2. Is there a workaround?

I don't really want to go down a dirty NSTimer route. As an aside, to rule out that this problem wasn't specific to my app I set up a dummy "Hello World" app and logged the app state methods to the console. The exact same process is followed when letting the device go into sleep mode naturally. The dummy app calls applicationDidBecomeActive right before the device sleeps.